# Hide password manager autocomplete in form fields onfocus

Tags: html, angular, password-manager

I have a saved passwords in a chrome browser via password manager and I have this following **input fields**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" formControlName="username" #log_name autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" placeholder="" formControlName="password" #pass autocomplete="off">
```

Everytime the page refresh the browser autofills the fields

[image]
[image]

what I did is a `readonly` and `onfocus` in input to disable the autofills

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" formControlName="username" #log_name autocomplete="off" 
readonly onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {this.removeAttribute('readonly');}>

<input type="password" placeholder="" formControlName="password" #pass autocomplete="off" 
readonly onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {this.removeAttribute('readonly');}>
```

now the autofills stops every refresh and it's good.

**Problem**

Is there a way I could hide the password manage autofill on focus of the field (*that black one*)?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Try adding autocomplete to the form as shown below

<form name="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" placeholder="" formControlName="username" #log_name autocomplete="off" 
readonly onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {this.removeAttribute('readonly');}>

<input type="password" placeholder="" formControlName="password" #pass autocomplete="off" 
readonly onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {this.removeAttribute('readonly');}>
</form>
```